# Mysql select order by date_format desc not working

Tags: mysql, select, date-format

I am making a query using mysql 5.7 with which I need to order a timestamp type field which has the date time and ampm format, but it does not, this is the query:

```
select ID, DATETIME from mytable order by STR_TO_DATE(DATETIME,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') desc
```

and show this.

ID| DATETIME 
2  | 2020-06-27 12:03 pm 
1  | 2020-06-27 08:15 am 
3  | 2020-06-27 04:23 pm

It should be like that...

ID | DATETIME 
3  | 2020-06-27 04:23 pm 
2  | 2020-06-27 12:03 pm 
1  | 2020-06-27 08:15 am

I have tried some variations like the following

ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DATETIME,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') DESC 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DATETIME,'%Y-%m-%d %h') DESC 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') DESC

and it still doesn't work, I appreciate in advance the help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the expected output, it looks like you could just order by ID desc.

```
select ID, DATETIME from mytable order by ID desc
```

Comment: I think it is an option, but perhaps not the most convenient

Comment: Ordering by ID might actually be the easiest and most efficient method (especially if it's a primary key column), providing that it is always assured that both ID and DATETIME increase monotonously. Alas, this is not necessarily true. I made this assumption once and it worked for a while, but then we had to import some old database. ID kept auto-incrementing, but the dates were from years ago and ordering by ID resulted in a very wrong order.

Comment: @DimitryRotstein- You are correct. I have faced similar scenario as well but looking at the question it seems that ordering by ID desc will give him what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should add your expression from "order by" to "select", so you could actually see what you're ordering by. Perhaps you made some mistake and STR_TO_DATE always fails, so you're in effect ordering by NULL. Actually, this is very possible, because STR_TO_DATE must receive a string, but it receives 'DATETIME', which is, in your own words, a timestamp, which is a number, not a string. If it is a timestamp, then all you need to do is to "order by DATETIME desc". It would be far more efficient anyway.

Comment: From the sample output it is clear datetime is a string assuming the select shown is accurate

Comment: Thanks, maybe I wanted to show a generic name however DATETIME could be called MYDATETIME.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you call it. Although, 'DATETIME' isn't the best choice, of course, since it's also the name of a data type.

Comment: "From the sample output it is clear datetime is a string" --- Not necessarily. The output might have been created by some program, e.g. Heidi, which automatically displays date/time variables as formatted strings for user's convenience.